# How to determine which button has been clicked in a while

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a while loop in php that fetches results of a query (a user post) and displays the data from the query. However i also want two buttons at the bottom of every post. I need to know how to determine which div the button was clicked in and then display the results of an ajax function in that div only, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply try

```
$('button').on("click",function(){
    var parent= $(this).parent();// will give you the Parent Object of the button, that has been clicked
});
```

So in var parent there's the HTML Element that is the parent of your button(the specified div).

Comment: you can put it in <script type="text/javascript">$('button').on("click",function(){
    var parent= $(this).parent();// will give you the Parent Object of the button, that has been clicked 
}); 
</script> <br/>and add that to the HEAD Section of your HTML file or at the END of the BODY Section which I would suggest, because its common to add scripts that are not related to manipulating the DOM while loading are added to the end of the body section. proove: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp